# span background-color is not working for last character space

Tags: css

I have a text which is contain a space in the last character, it seems like i unable to highlight the space at firefox. Does anyone know why? Is that a known issue for firefox?

```
.highlight{
 background-color: #C8C8C8 !important;
}
<span class="highlight">Test </span>

<span class="highlight">Text</span>
```

Notes:

1. I cannot use `inline-block`.
2. I cannot use `&nbsp;`.
3. Must able to highlight both text with space and text without space.

Comment: you can use `padding` or `&nbsp;` for that as @praveen suggested you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do that with `white-space` property

```html
<span style="white-space:pre-wrap;background-color: #C8C8C8 !important;">Test </span>
```

Comment: It seems like putting white-space:pre; solved my problem

Comment: white-space:pre; will have problem if my text is too long.
pre-wrap looks like OK.

Comment: white-space property is  good for this case because it specifies how white-space is handled in an element

Comment: Yes. thx all. i am using white-space:pre-wrap. thx for ur advice.

Answer (score 2):

Try giving a non-breaking space:

```
<span style="background-color: #C8C8C8 !important;">Test&nbsp;</span>
```

If you are not okay in using `&nbsp;` you can add padding. Both demo:

```html
<span style="background-color: #C8C8C8;">NBSP&nbsp;</span>
<span style="background-color: #C8C8C8; padding-right: 5px;">Padding </span>
```

Comment: Ya know. i hope i can do it without adding a nbsp.

Comment: If you need a solution you need to use this. By the way, spaces are not considered as a valid DOM element. That's the reason it won't work for you. What's the problem if you use `&nbsp;`?

Comment: Or, there's another way... Use padding?

Comment: yup this solution is great.

Comment: @MahJinKhai Check it out.

Comment: @Amitsingh I added another variant of the solution. Have a look?

Comment: Sorry guys, i am working on very detailed task here, and it can't be replaced by &nbsp;, neither inner-block won't work as well. but i think i have to accept that is it not a valid dom element.

Comment: @MahJinKhai Can't you use `padding`? It doesn't need an `inline-block`. By the way, `inline-block` doesn't work.

Comment: Padding it would works but the problem is.. the css might want to be used by other kind of text too (those without space at last character, or etc).

Comment: Sorry, maybe i should explained better. but thx for ur suggestion

Comment: @MahJinKhai Can't you add a separate class with `padding` in it?

Comment: Ya, that's one of the workaround. but my team prefer a single css to handle all the cases and avoid using java script to do comparison.

Comment: @MahJinKhai Either you are not using CSS correctly or your HTML is not right. Do you mind if I analyse your code? You can trust me, I am a HTML & CSS Expert.

Comment: @MahJinKhai Is there a reason you removed the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<span style="background-color: #C8C8C8 !important;display:inline-block;padding-right:10px">Test </span>
```

Comment: The answer has no explanation, plus it is not worth than already posted answer. The OP says he can't use `inline-block`.

Comment: @MaheswaranS Without `inline-block`, `padding` alone works buddy.

Comment: thanks praveen, yesterday only i am reading about you, also send the FB friend request to you...

Comment: thanks a lot... i think you chennai.. will chat later on FB